# Prison in Halacha

Tags: halacha-theory, beit-din-court, criminal-procedure

I realized that nowhere (as far as I can tell) is there a reference to prison being a punishment in the Torah. The closest I even come to someone being kept in prison is the man found gathering sticks on Shabbos, who was "put under guard" until they figured out what to do to him. ([Bamidbar 15:34](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9943/jewish/Chapter-15.htm#v=34))

Does the concept of prison exist in the Jewish legal system?