# Why does the Torah not include jail as punishment?

Tags: reward-punishment

The Torah does not include jail as punishment for transgressions.  Death, flogging, fines, shunning, yes, but not jail.  Do our sources comment on that?  Where?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35229/does-the-torah-ever-mention-jail-as-a-punishment-for-a-crime

Comment: and: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/96788/prison-in-halacha